# select value of a dropdown menu (second colume)

Tags: ms-access, vba

im working on an acces db and im strugling on my vba code

[this is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjfSg.jpg)

and this is my code:

```
Private Sub cmd_openreport_Click()

'Set Variables
Dim Report
Dim Etikette
Dim amount_of_copies
Dim SQL As String


DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff) 'Turns Off Warnings

Etikette = comb_etiketten_auswahl 'Etikette Equals the comb_etiketten_auswahl value
Report = comb_etiketten_layout 'Report equals the value in the dropdown list
'SQL = "SELECT [qry_WEZ_TAB].[Anzahl_Etiketten] FROM [qry_WEZ_TAB];


'If The Etiketten Dropdown is empty message to client
If Etikette <> "" Then
Else
MsgBox "Bitte wählen Sie einen Datensatz aus."
Exit Sub
End If

'If The Report Dropdown is empty message to client
If Report <> "" Then
Else
MsgBox "Bitte wählen Sie eine Etikettenauswahl aus."
Exit Sub
End If

'DoCmd.RunSQL SQL



DoCmd.OpenReport Report, acViewReport 'Open report
DoCmd.PrintOut , , , acHigh,amount_of_copies
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn) 'Turns Warnings back On
End Sub
```

the problem is *HERE:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport Report, acViewReport 'Open report
DoCmd.PrintOut , , , acHigh,*HERE
DoCmd.Close
```

The value ther is the amount of copies printed out.... the problem is that value is set in my db but my idea was to use:

```
docmd.runsql SQL
```

as in my code set to:

```
"SELECT [qry_WEZ_TAB].[Anzahl_Etiketten] FROM [qry_WEZ_TAB];"
```

but the problem is that even that the sql command is correct i'll get an error...

any idea how to fix this issue??

if you have an alternate idea how to get that amount of copyes from the tab feel free to comment^^

**EDIT :**

**This question is Irelevant and does not have a purpose anymore!
it was an internal script mistake!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was way to much into the sql i goth a solution now:

```
Private Sub cmd_openreport_Click()

'Set Variables
Dim Report
Dim Etikette
Dim anzahl
Dim SQL As String


DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff) 'Turns Off Warnings

Etikette = comb_etiketten_auswahl 'Etikette Equals the comb_etiketten_auswahl value
Report = comb_etiketten_layout 'Report equals the value in the dropdown list
anzahl = Forms!frm_Hauptmenu!comb_etiketten_auswahl.Column(1)


MsgBox anzahl

'If The Etiketten Dropdown is empty message to client
If Etikette <> "" Then
Else
MsgBox "Bitte wählen Sie einen Datensatz aus."
Exit Sub
End If

'If The Report Dropdown is empty message to client
If Report <> "" Then
Else
MsgBox "Bitte wählen Sie eine Etikettenauswahl aus."
Exit Sub
End If


DoCmd.OpenReport Report, acViewReport 'Open report
DoCmd.PrintOut , , , acHigh, anzahl
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn) 'Turns Warnings back On
End Sub
```

hope this can help anyone of you guys

Answer (score 1):

`docmd.runsql` is for *action* queries (Insert,Delete,Append) but doesn't return a recordset (for Select queries).

If "Anzahl_Etiketten" returns only 1 value (the number of labels) then try [dlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937):

```
DoCmd.PrintOut , , , acHigh,dlookup("Anzahl_Etiketten","qry_WEZ_TAB")
```